# Test and return at the start of a function vs nested if

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns

The following two pieces of code have the exact same behaviour, and each has its own merits:
single return vs nesting depth.

The middle of option B could be put inside a function to remove the nesting.

Option A.

```
void func(A * a, B * b)
{
  if (a == NULL) { return; }
  if (b == NULL) { return; }
  // Do some stuff
}
```

or Option B.

```
void func(A * a, B * b)
{
  if (a != NULL) 
  { 
    if (b != NULL) 
    { 
       // Do some stuff
    }
  }
}
```

I guess consistency is probably the most important.
Is there anything I am missing which gives one option substantial benefits over the other?

Thanks

Comment: This is really 95% opinion. In mine, single-return is not a goal to strive for and low indentation is, so option A is vastly superior, but that's just that, my opinion.

Comment: thanks for the input, I didn't mean to make an opinion based question, my specific question was "Is there anything I am missing which gives one option substantial benefits over the other?"

Comment: Maybe only one thing. If you are not going to store `a` nor `b` then you may use references, which by contract guarantee that `a` and `b` is not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no objective, technical killer argument to make one option superior to the other, so it really comes down to opinion. Do you prefer low indentation or do you prefer single return?

In some cases, maybe one version inhibits RVO for the compiler. But that's as far as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

in option A you can just chek if any of two is null in single if(...) as:

```
void func(A * a, B * b)
{
  if (a == NULL || b == NULL) { return; }
  // Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: And actually this kind of fits both options A and B.

Comment: yes, this fits for both
The entire post is opinion-based

Comment: And in option B you can just check `if (a != NULL && b != NULL)`.